# How to bind TextBox.Lines to BindingList<string> in WinForms in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, binding

I have

```
private BindingList<string> log;
```

And I have multi line logTextBox on my form.
How Can I bind "log" list to that textbox?

I don't need 2 way bind. One way bind from log to texbox would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly bind from `BindingList<string>` to `TextBox` since `Lines` property in `TextBox` is of type `string[]` not `BindingList<string>`.

You need a `string[]` property, and a property change notification to the same.

Here is a example of how you do that.

```
public class LinesDataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BindingList<string> lines = new BindingList<string>();

    public LinesDataSource()
    {
        lines.ListChanged += (sender, e) => OnPropertyChanged("LinesArray");
    }

    public BindingList<string> Lines
    {
        get { return lines; }
    }

    public string[] LinesArray
    {
        get
        {
            return lines.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in your form/user control

```
private LinesDataSource dataSource = new LinesDataSource();

private void Setup()
{
    textBox.DataBindings.Add("Lines", dataSource, "LinesArray");
    Populate();
}

private void Populate()
{
    dataSource.Lines.Add("whatever");
}
```